# Best SAS formats to be used for numbers with lots of digits before and after decimal

Tags: sas

I would like to read and display numbers like below using `infile` statement -

- 0.02133322413531
- 25895449673.5189
- 190848802804.89248974

without loosing any of the digits ( significant and non significant both) from a flat file which are the best formats to use in for - input , informat and format.

**EDIT:**

Have tried below so far, digits getting truncated for the last one , rest two are coming fine

```
data _null_;
infile datalines;
format x BEST32.;
input x : BEST32.;
put x=;
datalines;
0.02133322413531
25895449673.5189
190848802804.89248974
;
run;
```

Output:

- x=0.02133322413531
- x=25895449673.5189
- x=190848802804.892   <--- Getting truncated

Comment: Because of the floating point limitations use character variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the default numeric length of 8 bytes, SAS can only accurately store floating point values to approximately 15 digits.  This [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#numvar.htm) best describes the reasons for this.

Or for further light reading, this [link](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm) provides more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

If you store the numbers as a character variable you will not lose any of the digits.

Every time you perform a calculation you could use the [input function](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000180357.htm) to convert to a numeric.

```
 input(number_string,format.)
```

Also if you use [Data Step 2 (DS2)](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ds2ref/68056/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0t0ndcsjh77d0n1xgmxohv4pmdk.htm) then you are not limited to the two [datatypes](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ds2ref/68056/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0v130wmh3hmuzn1t7y5y4pgxa69.htm), you could also use `decimal(p,q)`, where (p,q) the digits to the left and right of the decimal point, that can be up to 52.

Comment: Thank you for your time. As for converting it to character, it would show all the digits but as soon as I would perform any calculations on it, the numbers would get truncated.
Also If you could post any example of DS2.

Comment: I was not aware that you wanted to perform calculations. Double precision is enough for most applications, so I would not worry about truncation there. Can you disclose what are you working on?